# Iterating through a list, to find item

Tags: python

So I need to make a code that checks to see if a pokemon has a type, and if it does it will add that pokemon name to a dictionary with all the other pokemon that possess the same type. All the info for this is stored on an a csv file. Also the indenting looks quite weird but it's indented properly on my actual file.

```
import sqlite3 
import csv

SEP = ','

def get_pokemon_stats():
    """Reads the data contained in a pokemon data file and parses it into
    several data structures.
    Args: None
    Returns: 
    -a dict where:
        -each key is a pokemon type (str). Note that type_1 and type_2
        entries are all considered types. There should be no special
        treatment for the type NA; it is considered a type as well.
        -each value is a list of all pokemon names (strs) that fall into
        the corresponding type
        """
    type_list = [] 
    poketype = []
    pokewith_type = []




    DATA_FILENAME = 'pokemon.csv' 

    with open('pokemon.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_file.readline()
        for line in csv_file:

        list_of_values = line.strip().split(SEP)

        type_list.extend(list_of_values[6:8])
        for i in range(len(type_list)):
            if type_list[i] not in poketype:
                poketype.append(type_list[i])
        poketypelist = (list_of_values[1], list_of_values[6:8])

        for i in range(len(poketypelist) - 1):
            if type_list[i] in poketype:
                pokemon_by_type[ type_list[i]] = poketypelist[i]
```

> **My Question**:
>   I don't know how to make python identify if the pokemon in the list has a type and if it does add it to a dictionary.

An example; if bulbasaur is poison grass, then in the dictionary bulbasaur should show up next to the poison and grass keys.

> **My CSV file look like**:
>   It has pokemon name, then a bunch of other stuff then the third and fourth columns are the two types.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: And what does the csv file look like?

Comment: I don't know how to make python identify if the pokemon in the list has a type and if it does add it to a dictionary. An example; if bulbasaur is poison grass, then in the dictionary bulbasaur should show up next to the poison and grass keys. @SpencerWieczorek

Comment: It has pokemon name, then a bunch of other stuff then the third and fourth columns are the two types. @slider

Comment: It's better to put the sample of data on your question, and it will be easier to read csv with pandas.

Comment: We are not allowed to use pandas unfortunately @RosdyanaKusuma.

Comment: Your example is incomplete or has something wrong. Everything under `for line in csv_file:` should be indented.
Also, whats the format of the CSV? What are it's columns?

Comment: I suggest you copy and paste a few lines from your csv, instead of that last part, including Pokemon with missing types. Also, take the time to fix the indentation, it will encourage people to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> data.csv

```
name,stuff,stuff,type1,type2
bulbasaur,who knows,who knows,poison,grass
fakeasaur,who knows,who knows,poison,grass
pikachu,who knows,who knows,lightning,rat
```

> pokemon.py

```
#!/bin/python

the_big_d = {}

with open('data.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_file.readline()
    for line in csv_file:
        l = line[0:-1].split(',')
        if l[3] not in the_big_d:
            the_big_d[l[3]] = [l[0]]
        else:
            the_big_d[l[3]].append(l[0])
        if l[4] not in the_big_d:
            the_big_d[l[4]] = [l[0]]
        else:
            the_big_d[l[4]].append(l[0])

print(the_big_d)
```

> Output:

```
{'poison': ['bulbasaur', 'fakeasaur'], 'grass': ['bulbasaur', 'fakeasaur'], 'lightning': ['pikachu'], 'rat': ['pikachu']}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming column 2 has the name of the pokemon and column 6 and 7 are it's types. And since you can't use pandas,

I don' know what exactly you are asking, but here is what I think you are looking for

```
def get_pokemon_stats():
    """
    Reads a csv file and returns a Dict of pokemons grouped under their type 
    """

    type_list = [] 
    pokemon_by_type_dict = {}


    DATA_FILENAME = 'pokemon.csv' 

    with open('pokemon.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
        csv_file.readline()

        for line in csv_file:

            list_of_values = line.split(",")

            for i in list_of_values[6:8]:
                if i not in type_list:
                    type_list.append(i)
                    pokemon_by_type_dict[i] = []     # Each "Type" key is a list of pokemons, change it if you want to

                pokemon_by_type_dict[i].append(list_of_values[1])


    return pokemon_by_type_dict         # Returns the pokemon dict
```

Is this the code you were looking for?